# In Karate DSL, how can I use the replace text for other data types such as int, float, Big, etc.?

Tags: json, rest, cucumber, karate

I found the below example on github.

- def text = 'hello  world  bye'
- replace text
  | token | value   |
  | one   | 'cruel' |
  | two   | 'good'  |
- match text == 'hello cruel world good bye'

What If the value I want to replace can only accept integers or other data types? For example,

- replace text
  | token | value|
  | hours   | 90 |
  | price   | 123.45  |
  | quantity   | 999999999999  |

I was not able to put the token inside another file because the json validator does not like the <> without the double quotes. any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace is meant for text not JSON, read the doc carefully please. First, there is no problem with numbers and replace:

```
* def text = 'hello <name> how many <hours>'
* replace text
    | token  | value    |
    | name   | 'John'   |
    | hours  | 200      |
* match text == 'hello John how many 200'
```

Now, if you are trying to fiddle with JSON, just use the `set` keyword.

```
* def json = { hello: '', hours: null }
* set json
    | path   | value    |
    | hello  | 'John'   |
    | hours  | 200      |
* match json == { hello: 'John', hours: 200 }
```

Note that the above would work even if you omit the first line. Also refer to embedded expressions as another way to substitute values in JSON, refer to the doc.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it's quite different, I had to read exampleAttachment.json file first and then set value for particular key.

`"example" : {"day" : null}`

At .feature file of cucumber, used `set` statement

`* set exampleAttachment.example.day = parseInt(date.day)`

Here I used another function for date create current date time.

Hope this helps.